# Apriori not running

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, correlation, apriori

I'm trying to find the correlation between my parameters using apriori but I get this error constantly, I tried using efficient_apriori but it only prints "2"

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

from apriori import apriori

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




%matplotlib inline




df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\2-Second Parameters chosen\\Half Year\\HalfYearCombine2.csv',header=None,low_memory=False)




data = []

for i in range(0,15578088):

    data.append([str(df.values[i,j])
for j in range(0,14)])


dataset = apriori(data, min_length = 2,
min_support = 0.2, min_confidence = 0.2,
min_lift = 3)

if dataset:

    print('not none!')

    print(len(dataset))

else:

    print('dataset is none!')
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-13-de4fe3df3901>", line 5, in <module>
    from apriori import apriori

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apriori.py", line 79
    print freqSet-conseq,'-->',conseq,'conf:',conf
                ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(freqSet-conseq,'-->',conseq,'conf:',conf)?
```

I don't know why it says missing parentheses in call to print while my print function looks fine?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how "print freqSet-conseq,'-->',conseq,'conf:',conf" doesn't have brackets? That means it was written in python2. You must've installed apriori for python2, but you are using python3.

Install apriori for python3 and try again.

Comment: @Jonathan DiMatteo, I'm really sorry since I'm new to all of this, on jupyter notebook it says I'm using python 3.7.3 , and all I did was type in pip install apriori, Thank you.

Comment: try `pip3 install apriori`

Comment: Seems like you don't have pip for python3 installed (pip3). Either install it and try again or learn to use a virtual environment (see here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `efficient_apriori` prints `2` is because it returns a tuple with `(itemsets, rules)`. To use `efficient_apriori`, you can do something like:

```py
from efficient_apriori import apriori
itemsets, rules = apriori(data, min_support=min_support, min_confidence=min_confidence)
if rules:
    print(len(rules))
```